# Scripting the sniffer built into Wireless Diagnostics

Tags: network, wifi, applescript, script

I'm interested in using the built-in wireless sniffer (accessible from Wireless Diagnostics by pressing Cmd-Opt-6) as a part of a script. Is there a way to control it via scripting, maybe AppleScript?

I need to:

- start the sniffer
- change the channel and bandwidth settings
- output to a file (as usual)

Can the UI be scripted with input events? Does Wireless Diagnostics offer any Apple events?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49317/194349), I'd suggest starting by symlinking the `airport` tool, which is the backend behind the Wireless Diagnostic tool:

```
sudo ln -s /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport /usr/local/bin/airport
```

and using it to sniff e.g. on channel `1` on your connection `en1` (see `ifconfig` to figure out which network interface is the wireless one) via:

```
sudo airport en1 sniff 1
```

which will create a uniquely named `.cap` file in `/tmp/`. Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to end the sniffing. (Note that `/tmp/` will be cleaned on reboot!)

Note that you can also use tcpdump directly for sniffing, without disassociating from wireless networks by:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/tcpdump -nei en1 -s 0 -w /tmp/scan.pcap
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I ended up doing something quite similar. I ended up using `tshark -I` rather than `airport <interface> sniff` for its capture filtering and ability to output to an arbitrary file (including stdout, allowing me to pipe the output to another command). Still needed `airport` to change the channel though.